# Spring/EhCache removing specific keys from the cache

Tags: spring, ehcache

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = "cacheOne")
public Map<String, Object> getSomeData(List<String> taglist,String queryString) {
```

I am using ehcache with Spring as shown in the code above. I can clear all the keys in **cacheOne** by doing this :

**cacheManager.getCache("cacheOne").removeAll();**

But what if I need to remove only those keys from this cache where taglist contains a particular tag? For e.g. I want to remove all the entries in **cacheOne** where there taglist contains a tag **cricket**?

Comment: Does something like `@CacheEvice(condition="#{taglist.contains('cricket')}", key="whatever")` work for you?

Comment: @geoand Are you proposing that this annotation be used on the same method which is using Cacheable? That's not what I want. I want to clear specific keys from a different method.

Comment: I am proposing you use `@CacheEvict` on whatever method of a Spring Bean actually fits your need. It definitely shouldn't be used on the same method as `@Cacheable`

Comment: @geoand Got it. But doesn't work for me. My use case is this : At some point I figure out that I need to evict all the entries from this cache for which the original taglist (passed to getSomeData) had contained "cricket". Now how do I figure out all the keys which have to be evicted?

Comment: I can't think of any way you would implement this using Spring annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid what you are asking will be on your shoulders.

What you are requesting, in addition to the caching you already perform, is a mapping between tags (cricket in your example) and the keys that contain these tags.

In order to store this mapping, you probably need to devise your own `KeyGenerator` that will keep track of this mapping in parallel of creating the cache key.
This mapping could even be smart if only a subset of tags are concerned by this purge need.

By default Spring will not keep track of that information for you, so you will not have a configuration based way of doing it.

The other option - not recommended - is to brute force by iterating over all the keys. And it should be pretty clear why this is a bad idea as soon as your dataset grows.

Comment: I am fine with iteration but is there a way to *decrypt* the keys that spring generates?